# Xcode Build Errors, Directory issue?

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, directory

I downloaded an iphone game kit for further development. I followed his instructions for how to unpack the files and installed Xcode. However, when I tried to build the game, I got 1,321 build errors, such as:
in the About.m section where an Error marker appears above

```
[App fadeToScene: [AboutMenuScene node]];
}

-(id) init
{
```

The error message says 'App' undeclared.

Another example in the About.m section:

```
self = [super init];
if(self != nil)
{
//add menu layer
```

> No super class declared in @interface for 'AboutmenuScene'

This makes me think my directories are screwed up, but I don't even know where to start to resolve this problem.

Here's what I have tried:

1. Put src folder into the Quexlor (game name) folder (failed)
2. Put src folder into the Quexlor.xcodeproj folder (failed)

In between these failures, I have deleted older copies of the desktop Quexlor, and uninstalled and then reinstalled Xcode and iOS sdk 4.3.

Comment: Is `-{id) init` accurate? That's an open curly brace, `id`, then a close parenthesis. Is this code and error message re-typed or copy and pasted? (Please don't re-type code or error messages -- it is too easy to make mistakes.)

Comment: hey sarnold, that was indeed a transcription error on my part. My point wasn't so much about the code, which I know is good because other people have successfully used the game code for their own projects, But my point is that there's some routing or directory problem within my computer that prevents the code from compiling.

Comment: **And btw**, I am able to get it running if I open up the iPhone Game Kit (which is located in the Downloads folder) and I am able to Build & Run the simulator, but when I click on Quexlor to run it, the screen is black, and the game presumably crashes.

However, it's interesting how I am actually able to get some result in the original download folder as opposed to when I try to Build & Run the Xcodeproj within the Quexlor folder that I copy-pasted onto my desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at [your post and pictures in the iPhone Game Kit support forum](http://www.iPhoneGameKit.com/forum/topic/build-failure).

I don't understand why [in this picture](http://i207.photobucket.com/albums/bb289/teh_Mac/src_2.png) the Quexlor.xcodeproj file is displayed as a Folder in Finder. [In this picture](http://i207.photobucket.com/albums/bb289/teh_Mac/Screenshot2011-10-15at22640PM.png) the Quexlor.xcodeproj file is displayed correctly as Xcode project "file". Which begs the questions:

- How did you copy the Quexlor folder from Downloads to Desktop?
- Have you tried copying it to another location other than Desktop?
- How do you open the Quexlor.xcodeproj?

It seems to me that copying the Quexlor folder somehow corrupts the Quexlor.xcodeproj file.

If you have the Quexlor project open, I suggest to expand all groups that it contains and look for any files displayed in red. If one or more files of a group are red, select the containing group and open the File Inspector (Command+Option+1) pane. It will show you the path to that group, which is often a relative path. Check that the folders on disk match the  path, or change the path in Xcode if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Since this post, I realized the debug version I was running was 4.3. Quexlor runs fine in the iphone simulator in v 4.2. In regards to how I copy the Quexlor folder, I right clicked on the Quexlor folder in the iPhone Game Kit folder and clicked "copy item" and then pasted that item onto the desktop. 
In response to the XcodeProj file as opposed to simply a folder: The picture taken at 3:00 pm was after I uninstalled Xcode, and then I reinstalled it.

Comment: Interestingly, the Xcode program is currently installed, and yet the Xcodeproj is still a folder, not a file. I open it via Xcode Welcoming box, where it is shown as the path ~/Desktop/iPhone Game Kit 3.1 and I just open that, no problems
Even though opening the Quexlor folder on the desktop reveals the xcodeproj as a folder not an executable.

Comment: I opened up the Quexlor folder and when I opened Quexlor.h (very first file listed as part of the code) Every single item after the #import command was marked in red.